# How to look in a file if already exist and only append new entries from json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Code:

```
with open('test.txt', 'a+') as viewers:
    while data['result']['list'] != '':
        for users in data['result']['list']:
            if users['nickName'] in viewers:
                break
            else:
                viewers.write(users['nickName'] + '\n')
```

The json I am looking to write to a file is like below. 
This json is from a live streaming where new users join all the time.
I want to write all users to a file, so something like 'when the value of "list": is not empty, keep appending new users from json'. When the "list": does no contains values anymore (because there the live streaming has ended and there are no viewers), stop.

```
   {
      "code": 1,
      "result": {
        "liveType": 0,
        "watchNum": 1161,
        "rank": 0,
        "duringF": 0,
        "list": [
          {
            "price": 86,
            "userId": 303249,
            "img": "https://mp5.facecast.xyz/storage1/M00/13/CF/aPODCl2RJBKARTtTAAAD9Xj8lkw004.png",
            "nickName": "ChillMick"
          },
          {
            "price": 53,
            "userId": 259943,
            "img": "https://mp5.facecast.xyz/storage1/M09/11/90/aPODCl1Pa22AK4WgAAADcFKVlIk698.png",
            "nickName": "\ud83d\udd37\ud83d\udd39\u24c2\ufe0f"
          },
        ],
        "earning": 14850,
        "likeNum": 5154
      },
      "msg": "OK"
```

How can I only append new entries?

Comment: I do not do json so this could be totally incorrect, but i think you can cross compare the entries with the new ones so you could remove it and not put it in.

Comment: that's what i am trying to do with the if users['nickName'] in viewers:
but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Do your json contient all the information about the session? Or you update the json file by calling an API?

Comment: I call an api to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

use a set.

Create an object that is hashable in the way you want it...

e.g.

```
@dataclass
class User:
    price: int
    userId: int
    img: str
    nickName: str
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.userId)  # assuming userId is the PK or hashable...
```

define `__eq__(self)` too

then use a `set()` to store all of the users... assuming this is an in-memory thing. if not, then use a normal datastore with a field that acts as PK.

Comment: ah that's out of my scope, I am still fairly new to python and this is too complex for me :D I had hoped there was an easier solution to check whether a string has already been written to a file. Something like ... if users['nickName'] in textfile break else append

Comment: you could do a search for a string using regex (have you use re.search before?), but i think the above solution will be the simplest for you especially if you are new.

Comment: Can you maybe hold my hand and guide me through it with a more detailed example of the above solution then? :) Like how to define __eq__(self) and use set() to store the users and then how to write it to a file? All in all, how to make it all work. It would be very helpful in learning these new things.